# KmlScreenOverlay Buttons

Tags: button, overlay, kml, google-earth

KmlScreenOverlay Buttons!!? real? how?

Any other way to put anything flash or html over GEPlugin?

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear what you're after.

If you're trying to make KML Screen Overlays, may I suggest you check out the tutorial and utility at http://freegeographytools.com/2007/the-kml-screen-overlay-maker-utility.

If you're asking whether you can put, say, a Form Submit button on top of a map in a browser, then sure. You can use divs to layer all sorts of stuff in a browser.

A really good example of this is the Beer Mapping Project.  Check out their [New Zealand](http://beermapping.com/maps/maps.php?m=newzealand) page and see the various items placed on top of it, including buttons, text and lists.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for the tutorial on screen overlays, but -1 for the bum steer on using divs to layer stuff over a plug-in. It won't work, unless you use an "iframe shim" workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> KmlScreenOverlay Buttons!!? real?

Yes they're real. But they're not as easy to use as HTML buttons... e.g. you can't just give them a text label. You have to use an image.

> how?

How to use them - see the tutorial that @Mark linked to.

> Any other way to put anything flash or
>   html over GEPlugin?

See also [How can I place a html div over the Google Earth plugin? Involves wmode, I imagine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506984/how-can-i-place-a-html-div-over-the-google-earth-plugin-involves-wmode-i-imagin)