# How do I get a draggable jQuery UI dialog to appear on top of the Google Earth Plugin?

Tags: javascript, z-index, jquery-ui-dialog, google-earth-plugin

Zindex won't work. The iframeFix variable doesn't seem to work either. The page won't seem to render anything on top of the plugin.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The there is no direct support for overlaying 'z-indexing' a div either in the Api or Dom. Using the 'iframe shim' technique is the standard workaround although transparency can be tricky.

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html

...Not sure if this is a duplicate question or not...
[How can I place a html div over the Google Earth plugin? Involves wmode, I imagine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506984/how-can-i-place-a-html-div-over-the-google-earth-plugin-involves-wmode-i-imagin/621830#621830)

Comment: It's the same idea, but I was hoping someone would give me a jquery specific answer to the question, especially since the UI dialog has some implications, like dragability. I actually worked this out, I just need to clean up the code and post it. Thanks for your response, Fraser.