# Place transparent DIV on top of Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

Is there a way to place a transparent-background DIV (a curved image forming the beginning and  ending of a menu) on top of Google Earth.

Thanks

Comment: using an iframe shim I was able to place a div on top of google earth, however the opacity of the iframe has to be 1.  Were you able to overlay a transparent div on google earth?

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a IFRAME shim solution.
Here is a link to very similar question: [How can I place a html div over the Google Earth plugin? Involves wmode, I imagine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506984/how-can-i-place-a-html-div-over-the-google-earth-plugin-involves-wmode-i-imagi)

Answer (score 0):

I use iframe divs on my website to create a menu - you can see my site here:
http://www.3dwhistler.com/

or for a simple example check out
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html

As for making it transparent, by using CSS, you can for Mac but not for Windows based browser. It looks really cool on the Mac, but instead of using different CSS per browser I am sticking to a 'common' look for now.