# z-index Google Earth without IFRAME

Tags: iframe, z-index, google-earth

I have created a widget to display Google Earth but Google Earth always be in the top, so I can't see the HTML elements like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506984/how-can-i-place-a-html-div-over-the-google-earth-plugin-involves-wmode-i-imagi). I searched in the Google and I see this bug can fix by IFRAME, but I don't want to use it. I want to use a other way. Anybody can help me? Tks

Answer (score 0):

example: google shim iframe explain http://lineandpixel.com/blog/iframe-shim-for-google-earth