# Google Earth Plugin With Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-earth-plugin

I am using google earth plugin on a web project with twitter bootstrap. When I use modals over plugin, modals stay back of the plugin in windows but not in mac. I searched this problem and learned that it is about google earth plugin does not let be anything over it. There exist an iframe solution [here](http://lineandpixel.com/blog/iframe-shim-for-google-earth) but it did not work with modals maybe I couldn't integrate it to my web page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I place a html div over the Google Earth plugin? Involves wmode, I imagine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506984/how-can-i-place-a-html-div-over-the-google-earth-plugin-involves-wmode-i-imagi)

Comment: Generally the method is the same but I couldn't do it with twitter bootstrap modals. Now it is ok as shown at my answer..

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own question. Frameshim method solves the problem. I found how to impelement it with bootstrap modals. You must put an iframeshim on modal's content div as below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="x" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="XXXX" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- iFrame Shim -->
        <div class ="iframe-container">
        <div class ="content-container"">
            <!-- content goes here! -->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">xxx</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>XXXXXXXX</h3>
                <div class="list-group">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">XXX</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <iframe class="iframeshim" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
            <html><head></head><body></body></html>
        </iframe>
        </div> <!-- end iframe-container -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And css classes are these

```
.iframe-container {z-index: 100;}

.content-container {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    }

.iframeshim {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10000;
    background: black;
    }
```

I hope this helps..